# Setting up Canon 430EX III-RT and Yongnuo YN622C-TX?

Tags: canon, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

Cannot wrap my head around setting up my Canon 430EX III-RT speedlite with this Yongnuo YN622C-TX trigger: whatever I try, the flash LINK light remains red, i.e. it is not connected to the trigger. Both devices are set to the same channel, the flash is set as radio slave, but it just does not work. Does anyone have this setup working?

Comment: Are they in the same group?

Comment: Yes, they are both in Group A.

Answer (score 2):

The 430EX III-RT's built-in transceiver cannot link to the YN-622C-TX. The Yongnuo 622 system is a separate radio system that's incompatible with Canon's RT radio system. While both operate on the 2.4 GHz band, the signal protocols are different. It's kind of like how wi-fi, bluetooth, your garage door opener, and baby monitor [all use 2.4 GHz](https://www.wired.com/2010/09/wireless-explainer/), but don't communicate with each other.

To use the 430EX III-RT together with a YN-622C-TX, you'd need to add a YN-622C transceiver to its foot. Or, if you want to use the built-in transceiver in your 430EX III-RT, you need to get a transmitter unit that "speaks" RT, like a Canon ST-E3-RT, Yongnuo YN-E3-RT, or a Westcott FJ-X2m (aka a Jinbei TR-Q7).

But. What I would recommend, if you're happy to ditch OEM and go for cheaper 3rd-party gear? Is returning both the flash and trigger and getting a Godox TT685-C (or possibly V860 II if you need extended battery life) and XPro-C or Flashpoint R2 Pro II-C. While Canon RT gear is great, and you'll definitely get the best service and compatibility with OEM flash gear, if you're getting into off-camera studio-style lighting, Canon's OEM and Yongnuo's 622 system is limited to only speedlights, and only Caonn/Nikon TTL/HSS support. If you want bigger lights, if you find the grass is greener over at Sony or Fuji, you're kind of screwed. Or you're going 3rd-party anyway.

Yongnuo's 622 system is good, too, and low-cost, but it's kind of a nightmare if you ever want to expand to bigger lights or add on cheap manual-only single-pin flashes for multiple light setups, since their YN-560-TX system is also separate and (mostly) incompatible with their 622 system.

Godox has [a full lighting system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/), with lights of all sizes that scale from a mini speedlight all the way up to a 2400 Ws pack and heads and a ton of stuff in-between at all pricepoints. And it's all in the same radio triggering system. that supports TTL/HSS for Canon, Nikon, Sony, Fuji, Olympus/Panasonic, and Pentax; and that support works cross-brand. So sharing the same lights between two different camera systems is easy.  The Westcott FJ system is similar, but only has one speedlight and two mini strobes in the system at the moment.

And. The Godox pricetags are similar to Yongnuo's (although, sadly, the lack of customer service is similar to Yongnuo's, too. Buy from a reputable retailer that will support the warranty period for you and offer customer support. In the US, Adorama and B&H do this.)  Westcott has better customer service, but higher pricetags.

Comment: Are you sure? The shop that sold the trigger claims it is compatible with Canon...

Comment: @eezacque, yes. The 622 system is compatible with Canon eTTL-II, HSS, etc. It's just not compatible with Canon RT. That's why Yongnuo also makes RT clone gear. As I said, all you have to do is get a YN-622C to put on the foot of the 430EX III-RT, and it will work.

Also, a guy in a shop has a vested interest in selling you what they have in the shop. Just saying.

Comment: To put it another way, the YN622-C transmitter is compatible with Canon *cameras*, but not Canon flashes without a 622 receiver attached to the flash.

Comment: In the U.S., Godox products branded as Adorama's *Flashpoint* line get NYC based service, rather than having to send them to China for service. Flashpoint versions of Godox products are fully cross-compatible with Godox branded products (and European "house branded" Godox products). The internal Li-Ion battery of the V860II/Zoom Li-Ion R2 is like having the recycling times and longevity of an external battery pack without the inconvenience of an external battery pack. The downside is that extra batteries are about $40, instead of about $30 for 12 Ni-MH rechargeable AAs with equivalent power.

Comment: The YN622 system is a very solid trigger system, but the flashes can be flakey. If you go with Yongnuo flashes, always have at least one extra with your kit for any mission critical shoot. You can also use your 480EX III RT, or for that matter any Yongnuo or other third party Canon compatible flash, with the Godox system by using a Godox X1R-C receiver attached to it.